# $.parseJSON Unexpected Character

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to send data from an html `data` attribute on a `span` element and receive it with Ajax and then process it with php and mysql and return the new value to my data attribute in html, but I'm getting a error that says "$.parseJSON unexpected character", can someone please look over my code to see if I'm processing the data correctly as I'm new to working with JSON.

**HTML / PHP**

```
<span data-object=
'{"art_id":"<?php echo $row['art_id'];?>",
"art_featured":"<?php echo $row['art_featured'];?>"}' 
class="icon-small star-color"></span>
<!-- art_id and art_featured are both int and art_featured will be either 1 or 0 -->
```

**jQuery / Ajax**

```
$("span[class*='star']").on('click', function () {
    var data = $.parseJSON($(this).data('object'));
    var $this = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url : "ajax-feature.php",
        data: {art_id: data.art_id,art_featured: data.art_featured}
    }).done(function(result) {
        data.art_featured = result;
        $this.data('object', JSON.stringify( data ));
    });

});
```

**PHP / mySQL**

```
if($_POST['art_featured']==1) {
        $sql_articles = "UPDATE `app_articles` SET `art_featured` = 0 WHERE `art_id` =".$_POST['art_id'];

        $result = array('art_id' => $_POST['art_id'], 'art_featured' => 0);
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
    else if($_POST['art_featured']==0){
        $sql_articles = "UPDATE `app_articles` SET `art_featured` = 1 WHERE `art_id` =".$_POST['art_id'];

        $result = array('art_id' => $_POST['art_id'], 'art_featured' => 1);
        echo json_encode($result);
    }

    if(query($sql_articles)) {

    }
    else {

    }
```

Comment: `$sql_articles = "UPDATE app_articles SET art_featured = 0 WHERE art_id =".$_POST['art_id'];` You need to fix this query (and the second one), they're both wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I haven't finish the sql page yet I'm just getting it working before I secure it up, but thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `$.parseJSON`, jQuery does that for you.

```
$("span[class*='star']").on('click', function () {
    var data = $(this).data('object');
    var $this = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url : "ajax-feature.php",
        data: {art_id: data.art_id,art_featured: data.art_featured}
    }).done(function(result) {
        data.art_featured = result;
        $this.data('object', data);
    });

});
```

You also don't need to stringify it later.